# CSP blocking the GTM

Tags: javascript, gatsby, google-tag-manager, content-security-policy, gatsby-plugin

I have a problem with CSP. He's blocking my GTM script.

[CSP Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqSee.jpg)

I'm using the gatsby framework, and this is the part of gatsby-config.js where do we have the CSP implementation

-------gatsby-config.js code---------------

```
                resolve: `gatsby-plugin-csp`,
                options: {
                    disableOnDev: true,
                    reportOnly: false,
                    mergeScriptHashes: false,
                    mergeStyleHashes: false,
                    mergeDefaultDirectives: true,
                    directives: {
                        'script-src': `'self' 'unsafe-inline' ${host}`,
                        'style-src': `'self' data: 'unsafe-inline' ${host}`,
                        'font-src': `'self' data: ${host} fonts.gstatic.com`
                    }
                }
            },

            {
                resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-htaccess',
                options: {
                    RewriteBase: true,
                    https: true,
                    www: true,
                    SymLinksIfOwnerMatch: true,
                    host: `${host}`,
                    custom: `
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
    Header set Referrer-Policy "same-origin"
    Header set Feature-Policy "geolocation 'self'; vibrate 'none'"
    Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" early
    Header unset Strict-Transport-Security env=!HTTPS
    Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' ${host}; base-uri 'self' ${host}; connect-src 'self' ${host}; style-src 'self' data: 'unsafe-inline' ${host}; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' ${host}; img-src 'self' https: data: ${host}; font-src 'self' https: data: ${host} fonts.gstatic.com; form-action 'self' https: ${host};"

    ## Cache
    <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
    </FilesMatch>

    <FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
    </FilesMatch>

    <FilesMatch "\.(css|json|js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
    </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>

    `,
                },
            },
```

I need a help guys. Tks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding Google to the `script-src` `directive`?

```
directives: {
    'script-src': `'self' 'unsafe-inline' ${host} https://www.google-analytics.com`,
    'style-src': `'self' data: 'unsafe-inline' ${host}`,
    'font-src': `'self' data: ${host} fonts.gstatic.com`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You publish 2 CSPs at the same time, one via `gatsby-plugin-csp`, the second via `gatsby-plugin-htaccess`. But both CSPs are different.
   Under normal conditions, the second CP will overwrite the first one, since the Apache web server overrides headers with the same name, and it executes .htaccess after 'gatsby-plugin-csp' has worked.
   But in some cases, 2 CSPs can be issued simultaneously, in this case the rules of a stricter CSP will work.

In any case, publishing 2 CSPs is bad, so you should either remove `gatsby-plugin-csp`, or remove `Header set Content-Security-Policy ...` from the `gatsby-plugin-htaccess` plugin.

2. The message: `Refused to load the script https://googletagmanager.com because it violates the following CSP dorectives script-src 'self' 'unsafe-unline' www.vidav.com.br` means you have to add the `https://googletagmanager.com` host-source into `script-src` directive to allow loading scripts from it.

But the problems will not end there, since GTM requires to allow many more sources. At the moment, minimal CSP for GTM is (if you do not use `nonce-value` token):

```
font-src data: fonts.gstatic.com;
frame-src www.googletagmanager.com;
img-src www.googletagmanager.com ssl.gstatic.com www.gstatic.com stats.g.doubleclick.net;
script-src 'unsafe-inline' tagmanager.google.com googletagmanager.com www.googletagmanager.com stats.g.doubleclick.net;
style-src 'unsafe-inline' tagmanager.google.com fonts.googleapis.com;
```

But if you use «Custom HTML tags» which use custom JavaScript variables, you have to add `'unsafe-eval'` into `script-src` directive.

Also you can to inject any third-patry scripts via GTM, for instance, jQuery. In this case you have to add CDN of this script into `script-src` directive (and maybe some sources into `style-src`/`img-src`). For more details pls see the test of [CSP for GTM](https://csplite.com/csp/test141/), where you can test exactly you GTM ID.