# Google Tag Manager - violates CSP

Tags: google-tag-manager, content-security-policy

I have found few question asking this already but any of them resolver my issue.

[70099772](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70099772/google-tag-manager-and-content-security-policy)
[76660492](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76660492/implementing-content-security-policy-with-google-tag-manager)
[69005123](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69005123/csp-blocking-the-gtm)
to name a few

I'm trying to implement CSP into site I'm currently developing.
App is written in Symfony and I have used [nelmio/security-bundle](https://symfony.com/bundles/NelmioSecurityBundle/current/index.html) to implement CSP.

After adding all required rules I'm left with last issue

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src <HERE ALL THE URL AND NONCES OF INLINE SCRIPTS>". Note that 'unsafe-inline' is ignored if either a hash or nonce value is present in the source list.
```

This error is thrown somewhere in `gtag.js` file where `inertBefore` is performed so I assume that it is trying to insert some inline scripts that CSP deems unworthy.

My gtag script looks like this (took it from "[Use Tag Manager with a Content Security Policy](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/security/guides/csp)")

```html
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script nonce="{{ csp_nonce('script') }}">
    (function (w, d, s, l, i) {
        w[l] = w[l] || [];
        w[l].push({ 'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js' });
        const f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        const j = d.createElement(s)
        const dl = l !== 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';
        j.async = true;
        j.src = 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
        const n = d.querySelector('[nonce]');  //<<-- This and next line should have solved it according to google guide
        n && j.setAttribute('nonce', n.nonce || n.getAttribute('nonce'));
        f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
    })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-XXXXXXX');
</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

What can I do to resolve this. Is there some kind of configuration that applies nonces to generated by gtm inline script?

Comment: Do you have the nonce in the source list for script-src as well?

Comment: @Halvor Sakshaug - yes I do

Comment: The script that I posted is invoking so this nonce is working just fine. Problem is with scripts added by gtm.js

Comment: @ciekals11 Did you find the issue?

Comment: @MaverickS no, I did not. I have postponed implementing CSP on my page for later because of this

Comment: Anything ever come about? I am running into this right now...